# Android: Sharing a common cookie store between two processes

Tags: android

I've implemented a persistent Http cookie store so that http cookies persist across app restarts (similar to this: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/PersistentCookieStore.java)

My app uses regular HttpUrlConnection and Volley.

The app consists of two processes - one for the main app UI and another that handles audio stream processing. The reason for the second process is to allow third party clients to use the same audio processing functionality.

The problem I'm running into is that the main app UI process gets http cookies from my server, but then requests that come from the second process don't have these cookies set because it's a separate process, and vice versa.

I thought about creating a shared object at the application context level, and then reusing it in both processes, but doesn't seem like this always works.

Example code in Application class (first process):

```
public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   mCookieManager = new CookieManager(new PersistentCookieStore(this), CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
   CookieHandler.setDefault(mCookieManager);
}
```

Example code in Service class (second process):

```
if(appCtx.getCookieManager() != null) {
    CookieHandler.setDefault(appCtx.getCookieManager());
}
```

It seems like I need a cookie store for each process, and some mechanism to sync them whenever a new cookie needs to be persisted or updated/deleted. Looking for some suggestions.

Comment: To be clear, the problem is that some requests coming from the second process are dropping the cookie - I'm using Charles Proxy and I see some requests missing the value in the HTTP headers. The cookies are persisted in SharedPreferences, but they're shared through the custom PersistentCookieStore object that gets initialized in the Application process. The app is targeted to devices >= ICS. My shared preferences is set up for Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS, so that should be fine.